# What is the correct way to maintain two different versions of the same project on github?

Tags: php, git, github, laravel-5, version-control

I must say am new to Git and Github, I apologize in advance for such a basic question. I created my very first PHP "larval package" project on GitHub. I made multiple commits and pushed them on GitHub using Git Bash.

Now my code is stable enough and in a production ready stage. How can I make it ready for everyone to download it?

Once, the first version is available for download, I like to make another version for development where I am going to be adding more feature for the next release.

I want to end up with at least stable version and another dev version. If someone reports a bug in my production version, I want to be able patch it and commit only to the version that is in production "so none of the new futures that is the dev will be included in the patch"

What is the best way to accommodate this? What commands do I use to create and easily maintain multiple versions of the same project where I can add new feature to one version and only patches to the other version?

Comment: Look into creating branches in Git.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do it

1. you work and commit on master branch. If anyone give you a Pull Request, you merge the code to master.
2. once you think the code is ready to release, create a new branch with release name by `git branch release_vX.Y.Z`.
3. while you testing your code, fix the bug on release branch the cherry-pick the changes to master branch by `git cherry-pick`
4. Create a tag on the release commit by `git tag`.

If you works on a large project, the better way is

1. you work on your personal branch like `dev`, feel free to check-in and commit your code to your `dev` branch.
2. If anyone create a Pull Request, merge their code to master.
3. Once you finish your work, commit all your changes to your `dev` branch. then

   3.1 sync `master` branch with github by `git checkout master && git pull`
   3.2 rebase your `dev` branch to latest change by `git checkout dev; git rebase origin/master`. You might need to resolve the conflicts and commit.
   3.3 merge all your `dev` commits to one commit. `git reset master` will reset the commit log to master but keep your changes, then `git add` all your changes and `git commit` to create a new single commit.
   3.4 merge your `dev` changes to `master` branch by `git checkout master; git merge dev`
4. If you think the code is stable enough, you can create a release for test and bug fix. If there is no test or bug fix, then you can just create a release tag on the commit by `git tag release_vX.Y.Z`.

Atlassian has a great document about git workflow for general software development base on Git. Here is the link https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Answer (score 1):

The optimal way to do this is by branching.

In your situation, this would mean having a branch called `master` (default), and `develop` (or something along those lines).

[This tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) is helpful in getting a hang of branches.

To create a new branch, use `git branch [name]`

To switch to that branch, use `git checkout [name]`

You will want to do your development on the `develop` branch. When the `develop` branch is at a state that you want to ship, you can [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) it into `master`, essentially pushing the new changes into the production branch.

Let me know if you have questions about this workflow and I can try to answer.

Comment: As mentioned by Edoardo, releases are another option. Releases can be used to tag a specific point in your branch as a production version. Using releases, you could use only a single branch.

Comment: Using releases doesn't allow you to **maintain** different versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Branches**

You can have the `master` branch for development and a separate branch (e.g. `production`) which merges some of the master commits. For keep tracking of different versions you can `tag` them.

With GitHub you can make `releases` which are essentially snapshots of the repo.